# Primefaces 5.1 Data table input text ajax

Tags: ajax, primefaces, datatable

I am using Primefaces 5.1 on glassfish 4. I have a view scoped bean behind an editable data table. As soon as the input text looses focus it returns to the old value and the cellEdit ajax event inside dataTable never fires. 
For the last 2 weeks i have searched and tried numerous stackoverflow/ BalucC blog/ coderanch etc but I couldn't solve it. Input text simply does not retain the input. The edited text is actually present in the view because if i again try to edit the cell the edit value is there only until the input text has the focus.

```
<ui:composition 
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:form id="formbio">
    <p:growl id="msgsbio" showDetail="true"/>
    <p:contextMenu for="biolist" widgetVar="cMenu">   
        <p:menuitem value="Edit Cell" icon="ui-icon-search" onclick="PF('cellBio').showCellEditor();return false;"/>  
        <p:menuitem value="Hide Menu" icon="ui-icon-close" onclick="PF('cMenu').hide();"/>  
    </p:contextMenu> 
    <p:dataTable var="bres" value="#{aResultEntry.biolist}" id="biolist" editable="true" editMode="cell" widgetVar="cellBio" >
        <f:facet name="header" >
            <p:outputLabel value="Result input for Receipt # #{aResultEntry.voucher.receiptno}" />
        </f:facet>
        <p:ajax event="cellEdit" listener="#{aResultEntry.onCellEdit}" update=":allresulttabs:formbio:msgsbio"/>

            <p:column headerText="Attribute" style="width:150px">
                <h:outputText value="#{bres.testattribid.attributename}" />           
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Result" style="width:150px">
                <p:cellEditor>
                    <f:facet name="output">
                        <h:outputText value="#{bres.resulttext}" />
                    </f:facet>
                    <f:facet name="input">
                        <p:inputText value="#{bres.resulttext}" style="width:100%" label="result"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:cellEditor>
            </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
    <p:commandButton actionListener="#{aResultEntry.saveBioGrid()}" value="Save" id="Savebtn"  update=":allresulttabs:formbio:msgsbio" immediate="true" />
</h:form>
```

My view scoped managed bean

```
@Named("aResultEntry")
@ViewScoped
public class AResultEntry  implements Serializable {
    ,,,,,,,
    public void onCellEdit(CellEditEvent event) {
        Object oldValue = event.getOldValue();
        Object newValue = event.getNewValue();
        Object evnt=event; 
        if(newValue != null && !newValue.equals(oldValue)) {
            FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Cell Changed", "Old: " + oldValue + ", New:" + newValue);
            FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
        }
    }
    ......
}
```

Comment: Though this may not be the answer to help many people but my problem was actually arising due to <p:rowExpansion> called further up in the hierarchy. When this event is called it causes the underlying <ui:composition> which includes an editable datatable to loose editing capability. A similar issue is can be found here (https://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=1727). 
However, as soon as any other event is called on datatable i.e. filter, the nested datatable again becomes editable.